# Android Camera2 recorded video always showing 30fps frame rate

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2, video-recording

Camera2 recorded video always showing 30fps. I am trying to record video at 240fps using Camera2 api.Even if i use slow motion video recording feature of device camera like Samsung s22, which can record video upto 960fps.It always show video frame rate as 30fps

Here is code snippet

```
  mMediaRecorder!!.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        mMediaRecorder!!.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE)
        mMediaRecorder!!.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
        if (mNextVideoAbsolutePath == null || mNextVideoAbsolutePath!!.isEmpty()) {
             mNextVideoAbsolutePath = getVideoFilePath(getActivity());
        }
        mMediaRecorder!!.setOutputFile(mNextVideoAbsolutePath)
        mMediaRecorder!!.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000)
        mMediaRecorder!!.setVideoFrameRate(240)
        mMediaRecorder!!.setVideoSize(mVideoSize!!.width, mVideoSize!!.height)
        mMediaRecorder!!.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)
        mMediaRecorder!!.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
```

I am also trying this configuration:

```
   mPreviewRequestBuilder?.set(
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE,
                Range(240, 240)
        )
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For normal fps range, you can query available fps range from camera's characteristics and set the desired value using target FPS range capture request key.

For high fps capture, please use CameraConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession

Comment: I am able to get high speed capture session upto 120fps. But how do i make sure that the video recorded on 120fps or not ?

Comment: There are player that lets you know the framerate. You can even try with MediaExtractor API in android.

But if you want to find that from camera2. One way is to count how many frames you received in 1sec you can do that by counting onCaptureCompleted received in preview CaptureCallback.